# {% if {club.c_type} == 'Tech' %} is giving error Code is working perfectly without it. Want to filter data on basis or Tech and Non Tech in same Page

Tags: python, django, backend

```
{% for club in clubs %}
{% if {club.c_type} == 'Tech' %}
SOME CODE  
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

```py
def clubs(request):
    clubs_data = Clubs.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'clubs.html', {'clubs': clubs_data})


CLUBS_TYPE = {('T', 'Tech'), ('NT', 'Non-Tech')}

class Clubs(models.Model):
    club_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=5)
    c_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    c_logo = models.ImageField(upload_to='clubimg')
    c_type = models.CharField(choices=CLUBS_TYPE, max_length=2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should only be:

```html
{% if club.c_type == 'Tech' %}
SOME CODE  
{% endif %}
```